# Simulate a web service from wsdl file

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm writing a program that interacts from with a SOAP web service. I have a wsdl file for the interface but I have no access to a server to test my program.

Is there some tool where I can load in the wsdl and it simulates the service? I just need to return valid looking data.

I can test the majority of my code my mocking the service interface, but I need to test the actual interface code as I've just had to change that with an updated wsdl file.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.soapui.org/soap-mocking/working-with-mockservices.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SoapUI can do it. It will run a local mock server.

Pretty easy to [set up](http://www.soapui.org/getting-started/mock-services.html), just give it your WSDL, a bit of configuration, and away you go.

Comment: This is exactly what I was after. Thanks

Comment: Is there any way of doing this programatically? I'd like to use this for automating integration tests.